# Can the :not selector be used with 'this'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I've got a `div` called `nav`, in which some other divs are placed. When I click on one, I want it to change the colour to orange, which is fine - using `this`.

I'd like the others to remain black when they aren't clicked though.

Can `not` be used with `this`?

```
$('.nav div').click(function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'orange');
    $('.nav div:not(this)').css('color', 'black');
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method instead of the selector:

```
$(".nav div").not(this).css("color", "black");
```

Or you could use the [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method

```
$(this).siblings().css("color", "black");
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add a class to all your divs and when you click on one, remove it with jQuery with

```
.removeClass("<name>");
```

Be sure to re-add it when you click on another one.

Comment: +1 This is actually a lot cleaner. And it separates the css from js, which is always good (:

Comment: that's also helpful.. I didn't know about .removeClass and .addClass. cheers mate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  Why not set them all to black, then set the special one to orange?

```
$('.nav').css('color', 'black');
$(this).css('color', 'orange');
```